# Building an OmniAuth strategy with a custom workflow

Tags: ruby, authentication, rubygems, omniauth

I want to achieve the following login workflow:

1. user clicks on login button
2. user gets redirected to our authentication platform
3. user submits the login credentials and then gets redirected back to our
   website via a pre-set callback URL
4. the OmniAuth strategy must decode the response (using our SDK) and
   save the result in the `omniauth.auth` hash

Is this process easily achievable using a OmniAuth Strategy? It's not very clear to me from the documentation, and the majority of already built strategies seem to be using the OAuth workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is quite easy to do.

**The OmniAuth strategy**

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Service
      include OmniAuth::Strategy

      def request_phase
        redirect AUTHENTICATION_URL
      end

      uid { @user_details.user_id }

      def extra
        @user_details # Return a hash with user data
      end

      def callback_phase
        # Configure Service SDK
        @user_details = Service.user_data # Make SDK call to get user details
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**The App**

1) Add a login button with the authentication URL:

```
<%= link_to 'Login', 'auth/service' %>
```

2) Add a callback route

```
get '/auth/service/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

3) Handle the callback response in the controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_create_by(service_id: auth_hash.uid)
    # Handle @user
  end
end
```